# What is the difference between "biz_inbox" and "setup_tool" attribution on the Facebook SDK for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-messenger

What is the difference between `biz_inbox` and `setup_tool` as `attribution` attribute on the Facebook SDK for JavaScript code below?

```
  <!-- Your Chat Plugin code -->
  <div class="fb-customerchat"
    attribution="biz_inbox"
    page_id="{PAGE_ID}">
  </div>

  <!-- Your Chat Plugin code -->
  <div class="fb-customerchat"
    attribution="setup_tool"
    page_id="{PAGE_ID}">
  </div>
```

Comment: Where did you get this code from? I can't find `attribution` mentioned on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/facebook-chat-plugin at all.

Comment: @CBroe I got it from multiple articles, one of them can be found here: https://thechurchfactory.com/how-to-add-facebook-chat-to-your-website/

Comment: Who says it aren't just two identifiers they made up themselves there. I am _guessing_ that `attribution` could be an older version of what the `ref` parameter does nowadays - and that's a value any developer can make up by themselves.